# Preformatted text starting with less-than signs is not displayed, if wrapped in tags instead of indentation

Tags: bug, markdown, editor

I have asked a question [Repair or rebuild driver store](https://superuser.com/questions/759703/repair-or-rebuild-driver-store) and had to add logs in there, these logs have lines starting with `>>>` and `<<<` symbol sequences. To my surprise, the preview and the actual visible version of the question do not contain the lines starting with `<<<`, and some more lines that come after these signs up to the *second* line starting with `>>>`, as if the sequence between these signs was eliminated as a disallowed HTML tag.

I expect this to be some sort of HTML tag search malfunction, as the text was wrapped in `<pre><code>` tag sequence. The bug does not occur if indentation is applied to all log text. You can check 2nd review for details.

Comment: Wrapping in `<pre><code>` needs manually encoding of, for example, `<`. See the duplicate.